# fixed partitioning without internal/external fragmentation

Tags: operating-system

I don't undertand how this question is worked out.

> Consider a case with fixed partitioning without internal/external fragmentation. There are five memory partitions: 500Kb, 200Kb, 300Kb, 100Kb and 700Kb. We have 4 processes with arrival sequence {P2, P1, P4, P3} that require contiguous memory allocation with size as follows: P1:478, P2:245, P3:128, P4:314. Answer the following.
>
> Fill in the table below with the allocated memory locations for each process, considering the fact that the memory addresses start from 0x0000:

I can't post the table. Here is an example:

> ```
> PID BF     FF     NF     WF
> 1 0x0000 0x0B00 0x0B00 0x0000
> 2 0x0700 0x0000 0x0000 0x0B00
> 3 0x0500 0x0500 0x0500 0x0700
> 4 0x0B00   FF       FF     FF
> ```